# Sync-ing files in Rails repo to S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, amazon-s3, rake

I am thinking of implementing a rake task that would sync certain files in my repository to S3. The catch is that I only want to update the files when they are changed in my Repo. So if file A gets modified and B stays the same, only file A will be synchronized to S3 during my next app deploy.

What is a reliable way to determine that a file has been modified? I am thinking of using `git` to determine whether the file has been changed locally.... is there any other way to do this? Does S3 provide similar functionality to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

S3 does not presently support conditional `PUT`s, which would be the ideal solution, but you can get this behavior with two requests instead. Your sync operation would look something like:

- For each file that you want on S3:

  - Calculate the MD5 of the local file.
  - Issue a `HEAD` request for that S3 object.
  - Issue a `PUT` request if the object's `Content-MD5` differs or the object does not exist.

That said, this sounds a lot like something you'd do with assets, in which case you'd be reinventing the wheel. The Rails 3 asset pipeline addresses this problem well -- in particular, fingerprinting assets and putting the hash in the URL allows you to serve them with insanely long `max-age` values since they're immutable -- and the [`asset_sync` gem](https://github.com/rumblelabs/asset_sync) can already put your assets on S3 automatically.

Comment: am i guaranteed to get MD5 back from S3 when sending HEAD request? I am not seeing when I curl

Comment: If you supply one in the PUT request, then yes. At present, S3 also uses the MD5 as the object's `Etag`, but it's conceivable that this behavior would change in the future.

Answer (score 0):

What about deleted files? The easy way to do it is to blast the whole directory with latest.

Comment: I want to rely on the `modified-since` header of the file so that my client knows when to or not pull the file.